# Как остановить пересоздания фрагментов в PaggerAdapter

Tags: android

У меня есть `PagerAdapter` и в нем 3 страницы. При прокрутке первой — сотни раз пересоздается вторая страницы. При переходе на вторую — пересоздается третья. При прокрутке третьей пересоздается первая, а, при прокрутке — вторая пересоздается сотни раз. Как сделать, чтобы фрагменты загрузились в `ViewPagger` и не пересоздавались?

Вот мой адаптер:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return CreatePage_Fragment.newInstance(0);
                case 1:
                    return CreatePage_Fragment.newInstance(1);
                case 2:
                    return CreatePage_Fragment.newInstance(2);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
```

Вот его назначение:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_viewPagger_1);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду вызов `onCreate()` метода фрагментов находящихся слева/справа от отображаемого - то это нормальное поведение. `ViewPager` загружает фрагменты слева и справа от текущего для ускорения их показа при их смене. Делает он это единожды для каждого фрагмента. При этом у него есть лимит сохранения фрагментов слева/справа от текущего. По умолчанию он равен единице. Засим при переходе на 3 фрагмент 1 уничтожается и снова загружается при переходе на 2. Это можно исправить задав больший лимит сохранения фрагментов. В вашем случае подойдёт `2`

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

---

А откуда

> сотни раз пересоздается вторая страницы

из вашего вопроса не понятно. Выложите код фрагмента. И поясните "пересоздается".

Comment: Все правильно работает! А соседний фрагмент сотни раз пересоздавался, когда я крутил вверх\вниз `ListView` в первом фрагменте. Не знаю почему, но это пропало... :\

Answer (score 0):

Ничто не мешает создать массив/мапу фрагментов и передать его в адаптер, а в самом адаптере в методе getItem() не создавать заново фрагмент, а дергать его по позиции из контейнера. Все зависит от размера массива и целесообразности пересоздания фрагментов.